# Regular expression for format xx-xx (does not contain letters)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am trying to use regex to check if the user input is in the correct format xx-xx (input only accepts numbers, does not accept alphanumeric characters)

I tried:  `/[1-9]{1,}\-[1-9]{1,}/` but when entering alphabetic characters still pass this test.

Can you guys help me. Thank.

Comment: You can use anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: simple as `/^\d+-\d+$/`

Comment: Your format is xx-xx, but you are using {1,} in your example.  Do you want one or more digits or do you want exactly two digits?     {1,} vs {2}

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is just fine, you just need to add positional asserts, "^" for the start of the string and "$" for the end of the string:

```
/^[1-9]{2}\-[1-9]{2}$/
```

It is better to put "{2}" if you only want xx-xx

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d{2}-\d{2}/
```

Worked for me.

Breakdown:

**\d** checks for a digit character, i.e. 0-9.

**{2}** checks for two digits next to each other specifically.

**-** just checks for the hyphen character.

Comment: Hi @Duncan, I want my string to contain no letters, how do I check this?. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can have several cases depending on what you are looking for precisely.

In case you agree that an xx-xx value can be 00-00 and any other value, you should use this regex instead:

```
/^\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

In case you accept that an xx-xx value is never 00-00 but can be 01-03 and any other value, but never 00-00, you should use this regex (a bit long, sorry, but does the job perfectly):

```
/^[1-9](?=[0-9])[0-9]-[1-9](?=[0-9])[0-9]$|^[0-9](?=[1-9])[1-9]-[0-9](?=[1-9])[1-9]$/
```

Enjoy !